# How to render WordPress rest api datawith vue.js

Tags: wordpress, vue.js

I'm doing project themming WordPress using vue.js and wp rest API. But now I can not render data. Here is my code

**app.js**

```js
var App = Vue.extend({});

var postList = Vue.extend({
    template:'#post-list-template',
    data: function(){
        return {
            posts: ''
        }
    },

    ready: function(){
        posts = this.$resource('/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=20');

        posts.get(function(posts){
            this.$set('posts', posts);
        })
    }
})



var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: postList }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router,
  template: '<router-view></router-view>'
})


**index.php**
```

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="white-wrap">
        <div id="app">

            <router-view></router-view>

        </div>
    </div>


<template id="post-list-template">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="post-list">
            <article v-for="post in posts" class="post">
                <div class="post-content">
                    <h2>{{ post.title.rendered }}</h2>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I don't know if I'm doing the right thing, because I am new in vue.js even any languages I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: hi, thanks you for qick respone. I think that i didnt get any error here.

This is all a got:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)  https://mozbar.moz.com/bartender/url-metrics


Bartender API access denied. chrome-extension://eakacpaijcpapndcfffdgphdiccmpknp/scripts/content_page.js:2560 

but i think this is the error of my seo Mozbar

Comment: @TruongManh do you have vue-resource installed? I see you are using `this.$resource`

Comment: @ Luis Villavicencio : Yes, i have installed it already, even the vue-router, but i dun know what happen. the data still can not be rendered

Answer (score 0):

Within your data function your returning the `posts` as an empty string. It should be an empty array.

Right now your trying to use v-for to loop over a string of posts. You should be looping through an array of post objects.

Also, instead of the `ready` function use an earlier hook like `beforeCreate`

That should take care of your problem.